# Updating TextVIew with Handler only showing last change

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I am trying to update a TextView every 3 seconds with a different string.  I have a handler and runnable set up, but when I run it, it automatically shows the last setText.  I have tried changing the ms to 3000, 6000, etc., and have also tried removeCallbacks before running.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout);

    final Runnable r = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            text.setText("1");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            text.setText("2");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            text.setText("3");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            text.setText("4");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            text.setText("5");


        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 0);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
private String[] messages = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int nextIndex;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.workout);
        final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        final Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                if (messages.length > nextIndex) {
                    text.setText(messages[nextIndex++]);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                }
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 0);
    }
```

Comment: you're a genius thank you so much!! works perfectly!